# Cannot Get Bearer Token for Azure via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, token

I am trying to get a bearer token through powershell, but I keep on getting an error that secret is not valid.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret
being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app
```

I have tried/created several different secret values, and they are not expired and most definitely valid.

This is the script I am using:

```
Function Connect-MgGraph -clientID 'CLIENTID' -tenantID 'TENANTID' -clientSecret 'SECRETVALUE' {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$clientID,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$tenantID,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$clientSecret
    )
    begin {
        $ReqTokenBody = @{
            Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
            Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
            client_Id     = $clientID
            Client_Secret = $clientSecret
        }
    }
    process {

        $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody

    }
    end {
        return $tokenResponse
    }

}
```

Comment: The first line of your code looks like a - broken - hybrid between a function _invocation_ and a function _definition_. As shown, it predictably causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The actual code within the function is fine. There is a problem with how you are passing and receiving the variables.
You can try the below which should work. The last line calls the function which you had defined.

```
Function Connect-MgGraph {
    [CmdletBinding()]
Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$clientID,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$tenantID,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$clientSecret
    )
    begin {
        Write-Host $clientID
        Write-Host $tenantID
        Write-Host $clientSecret
        $ReqTokenBody = @{
            Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
            Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
            client_Id     = $clientID
            Client_Secret = $clientSecret
        }
    }
    process {

        $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody

    }
    end {
        return $tokenResponse
    }
}

Connect-MgGraph -clientID <your-client-id> -tenantID <your-tenant-id> -clientSecret <your-secret>
```